# Why does full text searching for string 'FDR' yields no results in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I am trying to perform a search for users based on a full-text search.

SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH ( name ) AGAINST ( 'FDR' IN BOOLEAN MODE );

However the query yields no results.  I can replace the search value with other strings and yield results.

I have even tried using a null stop word list with no success.  The problem seems to with this particular string.

Comment: What string is in the name column that you think it should match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)

> The default minimum value is four
>   characters; the default maximum is
>   version dependent. If you change
>   either value, you must rebuild your
>   FULLTEXT indexes.
>
> The minimum and maximum lengths of
>   words to be indexed are defined by the
>   ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len
>   system variables.

Also see [Server System Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html)

Comment: I had built my index with the ft_min_word_len = 4 and subsequently lowered it to 3.  However, I did realize that FULLTEXT indexes needed to be rebuilt.  

Is there way to rebuild them without dropping and rebuilding them?

Comment: "To rebuild the indexes in this case, it is sufficient to do a QUICK repair operation:"

mysql> REPAIR TABLE tbl_name QUICK;" 

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Answer (score 4):

If [this article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1578331/Using-Fulltext-Indexes-in-MySQL---Part-1.htm) is still valid, then it's because MySQL fulltext indexing doesn't index words <= 3 characters long.